# Menu hover off color

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

Struggling with figuring out the CSS class for hover-off color for the main menu when the cursor is in the submenu. The usual a: and a:hover do not do anything.

The lighter color of the menu needs to be changed to a darker one. At this time of the day it is unreadable light color [current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZLYr.png).

[Website link](https://liedaga.liepaja.edu.lv/).

Answer (score 0):

Hello (Sorry for my english), your color rule is on row 754 and the whole thingy with the color rule looks like this.

```
html.colibri-wp-theme #colibri .style-9 > div > .colibri-menu-container > ul.colibri-menu > li > a {
font-family: Tinos;
font-weight: 500;
text-transform: initial;
font-size: 18pt;
line-height: 1em;
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #506ef2;
```

}

The hover color is in an other css file of some reason but a tip use the inpector on your web browser i used it and found the non hover class.

Comment: That doesn't solve it. The color: #506ef2; is a different color. Tried code inspector and tried changing every single instance of "color" to a different one. Also tried custom CSS rule in Wordpress custom CSS.  Usually that way, I could override any CSS rule. Not this time. The color stays. It seems it is hard-wired somewhere deeper than my knowledge.

The only thing I could change was the underscore line color that goes below the menu text.

Comment: It worked for me. I think i changed something else to that i don't have in my mind right now but it really worked out great for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Use as this way with :after & :focus with code.**

```
 html.colibri-wp-theme #colibri .style-9 > div > .colibri-menu-container > ul.colibri-menu > li > a:hover, html.colibri-wp-theme #colibri .style-9 > div > .colibri-menu-container > ul.colibri-menu > li > a:after, html.colibri-wp-theme #colibri .style-9 > div > .colibri-menu-container > ul.colibri-menu > li > a:focus{
        color: #4e85fc;
    }
```

**lemme know once this ok. I want help you for fix this.**

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your input, but unfortunately this doesn't work.